# Writing to file Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, text-files

I write to a text file like so:

```
void writeText(char* desc){
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen ("CycleTestInfo.txt","a+");
    fputs (desc,pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
}
```

I embed this in a for loop and I want to write to the file the loop that I am on:

```
for(int i=0; i<cycles; i++){
    char* cycle="--NEW CYCLE "+(char)i+"---\r\n";
    writeText(cycle);
}
```

However, I get `error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers` at the line where I declare `cycle`. How can I declare the the variable so that I can include the cycle number, `i` and also add a string to both sides?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you concatenate strings in C++.

You can either use `sprintf` or `std::string`.

The latter is more C++-ish::

```
std::string cycle("--NEW CYCLE");
cycle += (char)i;
cycle += "---\r\r";

writeText(cycle.c_str();
```

Note that you must also change the function signature to:

```
void writeText(const char* desc)
```

since `string::c_str()` returns a `const char*`.

Or you could use a `stringstream`, but that's a bit of overkill in this case. Worth looking into it though.

The reason you're getting an error is that `"--NEW CYCLE "` is a `const char*` in C++, not a `std::string`.

You **could** edit your line to work:

```
const char* cycle= (std::string("--NEW CYCLE ")+(char)i+"---\r\n").c_str();
```

but I wouldn't do that. It looks ugly.

Comment: @moesef it seems like a different problem. Ask another question with the updated code.

Comment: for completeness sake it should be `cycle+='0'+(char)i;` for `i` to show up in the text file.

Comment: You can't edit your line like that to work, the string is a temporary so the .c_str() will be invalidated the line after that statement, which means cycle will be a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fprintf` to write formatted text to a file:

```
fprintf(FILE, "--NEW CYCLE %d ---\r\n", i);
```

Comment: this works except it doesn't append the last cycle to the end of the file. so the  first entry into the file is the last entry to be put into it.

Answer (score 1):

That is not C++ that is C. a `char *` is not a string, it is a pointer to a char or to the start of several char values.

In C++ you use `std::string` as the string class.

The correct way however to output the text would be:

```
os << "--NEW CYCLE " << i << "---\r\n";
```

where `os` is an output stream

If you want to create a string that way, use `ostringstream` as the streaming class and then use `.str()` to get the string out of it.

Comment: What do you mean it's not C++, but C?

Comment: he means that `cstdio` is part of the C library. But you can still use it in C++. I'm using it because it is easier to append to the end of a file than `fstream`.

Comment: You can use cstdio in C++ and indeed if you are implementing iostream you are likely to do so in terms of the C standard library using cstdio.

There is a C++ style of writing though, in particular using std::string most of the time when you want to handle strings to store them, or streams to build them or write data in string format.

In some ways for me the biggest flaw in iostream is that the formatting gets embedded in the stream and not the object being printed.

Look at the horrible "side effect" of printing something to standard output in hex.